# Dijkstra's two-stack algorithm for expression evaluation

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I'm reading a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) on algorithms and data structures and try to follow the examples. What I try to implement is Dijkstra's two-stack algorithm for expression evaluation. It takes input in form of a string like `( 1 + 2 ) * 3` and then evaluates the expression. My code compiles but it doesn't produce correct output.

The output for above expression is:

```
3.0
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Eval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "( 1 + 2 ) * 3";
        evaluateAndPrintResult(s);
    }
    public static void evaluateAndPrintResult(String s)
    {
        String[] str = s.split("\\s+");
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(String ss : str)
            q.add(ss);
        Stack<String> ops = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<Double>();
        while (!q.isEmpty())
        { // Read token, push if operator.
            String token = q.poll();
            if (token.equals("(")) ;
            else if (token.equals("+")) ops.push(s);
            else if (token.equals("-")) ops.push(s);
            else if (token.equals("*")) ops.push(s);
            else if (token.equals("/")) ops.push(s);
            else if (token.equals("sqrt")) ops.push(s);
            else if (token.equals(")"))
            { // Pop, evaluate, and push result if token is ")".
                String op = ops.pop();
                double v = vals.pop();
                if (op.equals("+")) v = vals.pop() + v;
                else if (op.equals("-")) v = vals.pop() - v;
                else if (op.equals("*")) v = vals.pop() * v;
                else if (op.equals("/")) v = vals.pop() / v;
                else if (op.equals("sqrt")) v = Math.sqrt(v);
                vals.push(v);
            } // Token not operator or paren: push double value.
            else vals.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
        }
        System.out.println(vals.pop());
    }
}
```

I don't understand the program well enough to correct it. How can I correct my program?

Comment: You're only calculating when the character ')' is found. If you change your input to `( ( 1 + 2 ) * 3 )` it might work

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida - nope! Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the several places where you use `ops.push(s)`. You should be using `ops.push(token)`.

You are pushing the **whole expression**, you should push just the current token.

This code correctly prints `9.0`.

```
public static void evaluateAndPrintResult(String s) {
    String[] str = s.split("\\s+");
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));
    Stack<String> ops = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<>();
    while (!q.isEmpty()) { // Read token, push if operator.
        String token = q.poll();
        if (token.equals("(")) {
        } else if (token.equals("+")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("-")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("*")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("/")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("sqrt")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals(")")) { // Pop, evaluate, and push result if token is ")".
            // Replace the top exp with it' result.
            double v = vals.pop();
            String op = ops.pop();
            if (op.equals("+")) {
                v = vals.pop() + v;
            } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                v = vals.pop() - v;
            } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                v = vals.pop() * v;
            } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                v = vals.pop() / v;
            } else if (op.equals("sqrt")) {
                v = Math.sqrt(v);
            }
            vals.push(v);
        } else {
            // Token not operator or paren: push double value.
            vals.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vals.pop());
}

public void test() {
    evaluateAndPrintResult("( ( 1 + 2 ) * 3 )");
}
```

However, the expression `"( 1 + 2 ) * 3"` still evaluates to `3.0`. To solve that you need to evaluate the last op you pushed, if there is one.

```
public static void evaluateAndPrintResult(String s) {
    String[] str = s.split("\\s+");
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));
    Stack<String> ops = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<>();
    while (!q.isEmpty()) { // Read token, push if operator.
        String token = q.poll();
        if (token.equals("(")) {
        } else if (token.equals("+")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("-")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("*")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("/")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals("sqrt")) {
            ops.push(token);
        } else if (token.equals(")")) {
            vals.push(evaluateOp(ops, vals));
        } else {
            // Token not operator or paren: push double value.
            vals.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(evaluateOp(ops, vals));
}

private static Double evaluateOp(Stack<String> ops, Stack<Double> vals) {
    // Replace the top exp with its result.
    double v = vals.pop();
    String op = ops.pop();
    if (op.equals("+")) {
        v = vals.pop() + v;
    } else if (op.equals("-")) {
        v = vals.pop() - v;
    } else if (op.equals("*")) {
        v = vals.pop() * v;
    } else if (op.equals("/")) {
        v = vals.pop() / v;
    } else if (op.equals("sqrt")) {
        v = Math.sqrt(v);
    }
    return v;
}

public void test() {
    evaluateAndPrintResult("( 1 + 2 ) * 3");
}
```

And finally - a much tidier way of doing it.

```
public static void evaluateAndPrintResult(String s) {
    String[] str = s.split("\\s+");
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));
    Stack<String> ops = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<>();
    while (!q.isEmpty()) { // Read token, push if operator.
        String token = q.poll();
        switch (token) {
            case "(":
                break;
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "*":
            case "/":
            case "sqrt":
                ops.push(token);
                break;
            case ")":
                vals.push(evaluateOp(ops, vals));
                break;
            default:
                // Token not operator or paren: push double value.
                vals.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s + " = " + evaluateOp(ops, vals));
}

private static Double evaluateOp(Stack<String> ops, Stack<Double> vals) {
    // Replace the top exp with its result.
    double v = vals.pop();
    if (!ops.empty()) {
        String op = ops.pop();
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                v = vals.pop() + v;
                break;
            case "-":
                v = vals.pop() - v;
                break;
            case "*":
                v = vals.pop() * v;
                break;
            case "/":
                v = vals.pop() / v;
                break;
            case "sqrt":
                v = Math.sqrt(v);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return v;
}

public void test() {
    evaluateAndPrintResult("( ( 1 + 2 ) * 3 )");
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. BTW, can we use only one stack to do this? I think separating the operants and operators into two stack may not be necessary.

Comment: I know this is old, but shouldn't the if statement be a while loop in evaluateOp?

Answer (score 0):

I have read this part of the book. The book mentioned that the code it presented has some assumptions that make it simpler.

The most important simplification is that expressions may either be:

1. A number.
2. A left parenthesis followed by an expression, followed by an operator, followed by an expression, followed by a right parenthesis.

That said, in order for your root expression to be recognized by the code, it must be enclosed in parentheses, i.e. `(( 1 + 2 ) * 3)`. Otherwise, your stack will not be fully emptied.